# Pandas JSON Normalize - Choose Correct Record Path

Tags: python, pandas, json-normalize

I am trying to figure out how to normalize the nested JSON response sampled below.

Right now, `json_normalize(res,record_path=['data'])` is giving me MOST of the data I need but what I would really like is the detail in the "session_pageviews" list/dict with the attributes of the data list/dic included.

I tried `json_normalize(res,record_path=['data', ['session_pageviews']], meta = ['data'])` but I get an error: `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shape (32400,) (180,)`

I also tried `json_normalize(res,record_path=['data'], max_level = 1)` but that does not unnest session_pageviews

Any help would be appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Can you please post the ```json```, not an image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to apply the following function to your json:

```
def flatten_nested_json_df(df):
    df = df.reset_index()
    s = (df.applymap(type) == list).all()
    list_columns = s[s].index.tolist()
    
    s = (df.applymap(type) == dict).all()
    dict_columns = s[s].index.tolist()

    
    while len(list_columns) > 0 or len(dict_columns) > 0:
        new_columns = []

        for col in dict_columns:
            horiz_exploded = pd.json_normalize(df[col]).add_prefix(f'{col}.')
            horiz_exploded.index = df.index
            df = pd.concat([df, horiz_exploded], axis=1).drop(columns=[col])
            new_columns.extend(horiz_exploded.columns) # inplace

        for col in list_columns:
            #print(f"exploding: {col}")
            df = df.drop(columns=[col]).join(df[col].explode().to_frame())
            new_columns.append(col)

        s = (df[new_columns].applymap(type) == list).all()
        list_columns = s[s].index.tolist()

        s = (df[new_columns].applymap(type) == dict).all()
        dict_columns = s[s].index.tolist()
    return df
```

by doing this:

```
df1= flatten_nested_json_df(df)
```

where

```
df = pd.json_normalize(json)
```

That should give you all the information contained in your json.

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you so much for this. If you wrote the `flatten_nested_json_df` function I want to say thank you again. This is something I have needed for quite a while now.

Comment: @hansolo Glad it helped! Happy coding!

Comment: @hansolo Just for the future and to not annoy others. Do not post images. Also, it'll help you get answers. :-)

Comment: Makes sense - Apologies for that! Will note for the future